# Consume a WF hosted in IIS as a WCF service using ASP.NET 1.1 Client

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation, asp.net-1.1

As the title says, I would like to consume a WF workflow using a ASP.NET 1.1 client.
The workflow is hosted on IIS as a .svc service.

I have a .NET 3.5 winforms test client that uses **wsHttpContextBinding**.

Because I need to put a WorkflowID in Context to have my workflow rehydrated and continued, I use this piece of code:

```
var Svc = new MyClient.MyService();

var Ctx = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Ctx.Add("instanceId", workflowID.ToString());

var CtxMgr = Svc.InnerChannel.GetProperty<IContextManager>();
CtxMgr.SetContext(Ctx);

Svc.MyOperation();
```

It's working fine this way.

Unfortunately, my ASP.NET 1.1 legacy appliction need to consume this workflow. I have setup an additional endpoint that uses **basicHttpContextBinding**.

I have read the context has to be passed to a cookie, and I'm stuck here as I have no clue about how to do this in the caller code.

```
MyClient.MyService Svc= new MyClient.MyService();

// How to set the workflowID ?

Svc.MyOperation();
```

How can I set the context with a workflowID in the cookie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no miracle nor solution. The workflowID has to be handled to the client side, which concerns me because the client is not aware about the server plumbing.